# How to leave left margin of 500px for all 3 radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to leave left margin of 500px for all 3 radio buttons.  How to do that?  Please see the screenshot.

[image]

Here's the code:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <input checked="checked" type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd1" value="1"/>
  <label for="rd1">radio 1</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd2" value="2"/>
  <label for="rd2">radio asdfg</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd3" value="3"/>
  <label for="rd3">radio</label><br/>
  <style>
    label{
      padding:5px;
      font-family:corbel,sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      margin-left:10px;
    }
  </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wrap them in a `<div>` and `div { margin-left: 500px }`?

Comment: try to add this input[type="radio"]{
  margin-left:500px;
}

Comment: Note: `<input>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap a div around it and write a css for that div. it will move your radio button content to your needs.

```css
label {
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: corbel, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#radioBtn {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="radioBtn">
  <input checked="checked" type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd1" value="1" />
  <label for="rd1">radio 1</label><br />
  <input type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd2" value="2" />
  <label for="rd2">radio asdfg</label><br />
  <input type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd3" value="3" />
  <label for="rd3">radio</label><br />
</div>
```

Comment: Note: `<input>` and `<br>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Warp your content inside a div and add `margin-left:500px`.

**Suggestion**

if screen width is `320px` and you will face align issue, instead use `%` like `25%` this will automatically align your content.

```css
label {
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: corbel, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.margin-left {
  margin-left: 500px
}
```

```html
<div class="margin-left">
  <input checked="checked" type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd1" value="1" />
  <label for="rd1">radio 1</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd2" value="2" />
  <label for="rd2">radio asdfg</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd3" value="3" />
  <label for="rd3">radio</label><br/>
</div>
```

**2nd method**

You can place `radio button` in center of page by following method.

```css
label {
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: corbel, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.margin-left {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="margin-left">
  <input checked="checked" type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd1" value="1" />
  <label for="rd1">radio 1</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd2" value="2" />
  <label for="rd2">radio asdfg</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd3" value="3" />
  <label for="rd3">radio</label><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: `<input>` and `<br>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in HTML.

Comment: @Rob ok. but that's the code mentioned in question and i don't want replace.

Answer (score 0):

Since both `label` and `input` elements dosen't have initial margins, you can set the display to `inline-block` (for example) and then  it will work.

Snippet:

```css
label, input {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 500px;

}
```

```html
<input checked="checked" type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd1" value="1"/>
<label for="rd1">radio 1</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd2" value="2"/>
<label for="rd2">radio asdfg</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd3" value="3"/>
<label for="rd3">radio</label><br/>
```

Another solution (like all other answers mentioned) is to wrap them with block element and then you can add `padding-left` like this:

```css
div {
  padding-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input checked="checked" type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd1" value="1"/>
  <label for="rd1">radio 1</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd2" value="2"/>
  <label for="rd2">radio asdfg</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd3" value="3"/>
  <label for="rd3">radio</label><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```css
label{
padding:5px;
font-family:corbel,sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
margin-left:10px;
}

.mydiv{
margin-left:500px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mydiv">
<input checked="checked" type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd1" value="1"/>
<label for="rd1">radio 1</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd2" value="2"/>
<label for="rd2">radio asdfg</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd3" value="3"/>
<label for="rd3">radio</label><br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
label {
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: corbel, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.grid .col {
  width: 50%;

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="col">Left Content goes here</div>
    <div class="col">
      <input checked="checked" type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd1" value="1">
      <label for="rd1">radio 1</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd2" value="2">
      <label for="rd2">radio asdfg</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="user_level" id="rd3" value="3">
      <label for="rd3">radio</label><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="col">
      <input checked="checked" type="radio" name="user_level1" id="rd1" value="1">
      <label for="rd1">radio 1</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="user_level1" id="rd2" value="2">
      <label for="rd2">radio asdfg</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="user_level1" id="rd3" value="3">
      <label for="rd3">radio</label><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col">Right Content goes here</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can try something like this. Grid layouts for it.